# Perl: Module to handle nohup, and process handling in general

Tags: perl, ps, kill-process, grep

I have a program with lots of `system` commands to handle searching for, examining, and killing processes:

```
system qq(kill $pid);
```

and

```
for my $pid ( qx( pgrep -f "$pgrep_re") ) {
    chomp $pid;
    ...
}
```

and

```
my $command_line = qx(ps -o command="" $pid);
chomp $command_line;
....
```

Not only is this system specific, but I'm depending upon the user to have these particular commands in their path the correct way, leaving me with a system security issue (like some joker setting `alias ps="rm -rf *"`).

I would like to do this stuff in a nice, *Perl* way which would be less dependent upon all of these system commands and be a bit more platform independent<sup>1</sup>.

Is there a Perl module? Bonus points for one that does it in a nice object-oriented way and doesn't depend externally with these very same commands.

---

<sup>1.</sup> A lot of this deals with using `ssh` and setting up tunnels, so since Windows doesn't have `ssh` as a native command, I'm willing to exclude it as long as this works well for other Unix/Linux systems.

Comment: Full path to `ps` to fight aliases? As for win/ssh, last time I've checked Net::SSH::Any worked (requires Net::SSH2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- kill: use the builtin kill (perldoc -f kill)
- ps: use search.cpan.org, there is UNIX::Process. In linux you could also scan through /proc/
- pgrep: combine ps with perl pattern matching

Comment: Forgot about that Perl has a `kill` command. I saw that UNIX::Process, but all it does is an `AUTOLOAD` of the `/bin/ps -o"$field="". Doesn't do anything more than I'm doing.

Comment: You might try Proc::ProcessTable. But this is not a perl-only module and requires compilation, so it is not clear if it works for you.

Comment: `Proc::ProcessTable` looks more like what I'm looking for. For optional modules, I usually check if the module is installed, and if not, use system commands like I do now. The ratings complain that the command isn't being maintained, but the source code was last changed just a few months ago. Those _unsupported_ comments may be a bit dated. Thanks.